# borsh.serialize is not a function

Tags: javascript, borsh, serialization

```
class Initialize1 {
  constructor({ nonce, openTime }) {
    this.nonce = nonce;
    this.openTime = openTime;
  }

  static schema = new Map([
    [
      Initialize1,
      {
        kind: "struct",
        fields: [
          ["nonce", "u8"],
          ["openTime", "u64"],
        ],
      },
    ],
  ]);

  serialize() {
    return borsh.serialize(Initialize1.schema, this);
  }
}
```

When I try to serialize data, I get a" TypeError: borsh.serialize is not a function."
What am I doing wrong?
Also I tried to make something with this code:

```
const borsh = require("@project-serum/borsh");

class Initialize1 {
  constructor({ nonce, openTime }) {
    this.nonce = nonce;
    this.openTime = openTime;
  }

  static initializeInstructionSchema = borsh.struct([
    borsh.u8("nonce"),
    borsh.u64("openTime"),
  ]);

  serialize() {
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1000);
    this.initializeInstructionSchema.encode(0, this, buffer);
    return buffer.slice(0, this.initializeInstructionSchema.getSpan(buffer));
  }
}
```

but error I get the error "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'encode')" too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    const buffer = Buffer.alloc(1000);
    console.log(
      "initializeInstructionSchema",
      Initialize1.initializeInstructionSchema
    );
    Initialize1.initializeInstructionSchema.encode(buffer, 0, this); // Notice the change here
    console.log(
      "initializeInstructionSchema encoded",
      Initialize1.initializeInstructionSchema.encode(buffer, 0, this)
    );

    return buffer.slice(
      0,
      Initialize1.initializeInstructionSchema.getSpan(buffer)
    );
  }
```

I solved this with a little bit of changes with constructor